# Sending text via ViewBag asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a string which I add in my controller..

```
ViewBag.mydata = "a,x,b,\na,y,b,....."
```

In my view in javascript code I call..

```
var myvar= @ViewBag.mydata;
```

when I see the view source html I find

```
var myvar = a,x,b,
            a,y,b,
            .......
```

I need myvar to be the string I sent in ViewBag..

Thanks

Comment: well, \n will do that to a string :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var myvar= '@ViewBag.mydata';
```

Seems you having that because with `@ViewBag.mydata` you outputing just contents of your C# string to make it as a javascript string you need to wrap that into quotes.

**Update 1.**

If you wan't to keep your `\n`'s displaying you need to escape `\` and that could be achieved by duplicating that sign:

```
var myvar= '@ViewBag.mydata'.replace('\n', '\\n');
```

Comment: Does not help.. it adds a quote in front and end but /n gets converted to new line

Comment: @Arnab from your question it seems like that should be an answer. Can you describe better what you want you acheive? I take that you want **\n** displayed on UI, right? How you are using your **myvar**?

Comment: My 'var myvar' code was in js, so replace did not help, but thanx to your providing the '\\n', I was able to solve the problem by sending the data from controller with \\n instead of \n and that did it..